# Why the memory not fully used to cache data

Tags: linux, memory-management

On CentOS 7.3.1611(linux kernel 3.10), My program is I/O bound that read disk device using **buffer I/O**, generally linux kernel may use the full memory to cache disk data as **buffers**, but it always left about 20G memory that not used, and kswapd daemon keeping to reclaim pages all the time.

top

```
top - 14:11:47 up 16 days,  2:42,  5 users,  load average: 2.92, 3.18, 3.37
Tasks: 329 total,   2 running, 327 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.3 us,  7.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.3 id,  4.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13175558+total, 22444704 free, 26496388 used, 82814488 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 10222934+avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   181 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  13.0  0.0   1395:34 kswapd0
```

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:       131755580 kB
MemFree:        21335956 kB
MemAvailable:   102232248 kB
Buffers:        75100216 kB
Cached:          6990768 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         69447392 kB
Inactive:       38154608 kB
Active(anon):   26890392 kB
Inactive(anon):   709920 kB
Active(file):   42557000 kB
Inactive(file): 37444688 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               180 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      25511156 kB
Mapped:            35036 kB
Shmem:           2090184 kB
Slab:            1835540 kB
SReclaimable:    1684472 kB
SUnreclaim:       151068 kB
KernelStack:       15536 kB
PageTables:        59556 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    65877788 kB
Committed_AS:    5750772 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      551220 kB
VmallocChunk:   34358888444 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  21006336 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      294840 kB
DirectMap2M:    11159552 kB
DirectMap1G:    124780544 kB
```

cat /proc/buddyinfo

```
Node 0, zone      DMA      1      0      1      0      2      1      1      0      1      1      3 
Node 0, zone    DMA32    785    898    869    489    260    227    442    316    142      0      0 
Node 0, zone   Normal  71568 1575732 446338     39      9      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

sar -B -r 1

```
Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (PZ-R-01)   02/09/2018  _x86_64_    (32 CPU)

02:13:57 PM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
02:13:58 PM 139388.00     48.00   4622.00      0.00 399474.00      0.00  17844.00  17908.00    100.36

02:13:57 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
02:13:58 PM  20986792 110768788     84.07  75421044   7021576   5743480      4.36  69832168  38119340       200
```

It seems that free memory pages is enough, why kswapd still reclaim pages?

// 2018/3/13 updated

It can use the almost full memory to cache disk data when updated linux kernel from 3.10 to 4.4, so it must be caused by kswapd behavior，and linux kernel 3.11 had improved the page reclaim behaviour.

see details:
[Linux_3.11#Memory_management](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.11#Memory_management)